# Why would a font loaded with google font API work sometimes but not always?

Tags: css, fonts, safari, font-face, google-font-api

I'm using a font from google and it doesn't display on my machine in safari, though I've seen it render correctly on other machines in safari. **What could be going wrong?** It works in other browsers such as firefox and chrome.

The SCSS line to include it:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic");
```

Alternatively, is there any way to debug the font family being used by an HTML element? I see the correct font-family referenced in the CSS, and the styling rule is applied to the element, but it displays as these weird looking blocks.

The "rendered" text:

[image: the rendered font]

the applied CSS rule:

[image: CSS rule being applied]

Comment: did you try opening the dev tools and seeing whether there are any console errors, or network errors involving the font? If so, can you add that information to the post? If not, can you also add that information to the post?

Comment: Make sure you did not fake the User Agent in the Safari _Developer_ menu. Depending on the UA, Google generates the CSS rules with different font formats. With a faked UA Google would then probably send font rules Safari can not use.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did, nothing related to fonts as errors.

Comment: @udondan I checked user agent settings, just set to default.

Comment: have you tried a non-scss plain "just a single `<p>` with that font applied" jsbin/codepoint/jsfiddle? (if so, can we have a link?)

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, debugging which font the browser is actually using is tough—especially since browsers have differing support for `@font-face` and the actual rendering of fonts varies from platform to platform. One tool that you might find handy is [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), where you upload an image of the rendered text and it tries to identify the font that is actually being used.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if it was actually rendering in something related or close, but since it turns all my characters into wingdings (effectively) I don't think it would have any bearing on what's being rendered.